# how to convert a delta to a string that you have entered

Tags: javascript, quill

I am entering a string to the `quill editor`. The `quill editor` convert the  string to a `delta` and saving it to the database. So I want to trim the string when I am retrieving it from the database but because it's a delta is trim the delta and all my styling is not working and it return an uncompleted delta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty old question but just in case the next one is looking for an answer I will explain how I fixed is. It's a way, doesn't really feel right... But it gets the job done.

You should convert the JSON, that's only understood by `Quill` as a Delta object, to normal content. This is just plain old html. Since we got the html as a string we can perform a `string.replace` to replace the whitespace with no whitespace.